# extract string conditionally from variable column sized text file

Tags: bash, substring

From a text file with variable number of columns per row (tab delimited), I would like to extract value with specific condition.
The text file looks like:

```
S1=dhs    Sb=skf    S3=ghw    QS=ghr</b>
S1=dhf    QS=thg    S3=eiq<b/>
QS=bhf    S3=ruq    Gq=qpq    GW=tut<b/>
Sb=ruw    QS=ooe    Gq=qfj    GW=uvd<b/>
```

I would like to have a result like:

```
QS=ghr<b/>
QS=thg<b/>
QS=bhf<b/>
QS=ooe
```

Please excuse my naive question but I am a beginner trying to learn some basic bash scripting technique for text manipulation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are those `<b/>` tags in your file? They're illegal html and seemingly pointless as well.

Comment: no , he use `<b/>` for formatting the code.

Comment: I am illiterate of html and didn't know how to format my posting correctly..sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use awk ,

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^QS=/){print $i}}}' file
```

This awk command iterates through each fields and check for the column which has `QS=` string at the start. If it finds any, then the corresponding column would be printed.

Through grep,

```
grep -oP '(^|\t)\KQS=\S*' file
```

`-o` parameter means only matching. So it prints only the characters which are matched.

`-P` this enables the Perl-regex mode.

`(^|\t)` matches the start of a line or a tab character.

`\K` discards the previously matched tab or start of the line boundary.

`QS=` Now it matches the `QS=` string.

`\S*` Matches zero or more non-space characters.

Comment: It works like a charm. Could I possibly have a little explanation on how each function makes it work please? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Using GNU awk you could also do `awk -vRS="[[:space:]]+" '/^QS=/' file`